# Write SQLite database remotely

Tags: python, sqlite, paramiko

I am looking for a way to take results from an SQLite database, select part of the schema, and recreate this on a remote machine via paramiko without the intermediate step of a local file or any form of remote file that is not a pure SQLite database.

This blog post sets up a nice way to potential get the part of the schema I want but I would have to dump this to a file then read it into the database via a remote script afterwards:

http://blog.marcus-brinkmann.de/2010/08/27/how-to-use-sqlites-backup-in-python/

I know paramiko can provide remote file like objects like this:

```
f = self.sftp.open(path, 'wb')
f.write(fileobj.read())
f.close()
```

Is there any way to combine some file object, StringIO, or byte conversion with one of the SQLite DB APIs in order to provide a way to stream a prebuilt SQLite database without extra file writes on the host or remote?

In other words something like this:

```
f = self.sftp.open(path, 'wb')
conn = sqlite3.connection(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct solution to your problem, but this is what a web api is for.  Building a REST-like api is probably a good bet.

Since you are already in python, I would take a look at [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) which can provide a drop-ship API using [django-tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) will be a less desireable solution if you are operating with an already existing database schema, although you can make it work.

You may also want to look into [Pylons](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), which is a more generic/barebones framework than Django.  All depends on what your actual requirements are.